# Is it necessary to write down() for every up() in migration in laravel?

Tags: laravel, migration, database-migration, laravel-migrations

```
class UpdateSessions extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
            Schema::table('sessions', function($table){
                $table->string('comCode')->nullable()->change();
            });
    }

    public function down()
    {
         // What should i write here?
    }

}
```

I have already created a sessions table writing a migration to change the column to be nullable.
Now i am confused on what should i write in down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `down` method of a migration, you undo the changes you made within the `up` method. This method is called when you rollaback a migration with  the `artisan migrate:rollback` command. In your case it would look something like this:

```php
public function down()
{
    // Laravel doesn't have a method to undo ->nullable()
    // so you have to do use a raw query in this case
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE sessions MODIFY comCode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL');
}
```

So if in your migration `up` you modified the column named `comCode` to be nullable, when rolling back the migration you'd need to update that column definition to make it not null, and that's what you do in the `down` method.

It's not necessary to have anything in the `down` method in order for the migration to run successfully, however once the migration is ran you won't be able to roll it back unless you have the correct code in the `down` method.

Comment: is it a good practice to revert the change using DB:statement? i have portability in my mind. this statement might work for mysql but not work for all dbms?

Comment: @alishaukat No, it's not a good practice, and should be avoided whenever possible. However in this case it was necessary, because there was no method available to abstract the query needed for this change. Most DBMSs require a complete definition of the column to alter it, and since the Schema Builder is oblivious to the column definition set in previous migrations, you'll need to specify them all again when applying the change (and that can have many implications because you might need to also redefine keys and constraints).

Comment: There a lengthy discussion on this particular column update problem [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/895), but there seems to be no solution in sight.

Comment: What happens if there is a null data in db ?  He insert data after migrate with null values. And you try to remove nullable in down method..  Its crashed.

Answer (score 2):

As of now Dec 2015, at least with Laravel 5 you can just write

```
Schema::table('sessions', function($table){
    $table->string('comCode')->change();
});
```

Note: this time there is no `nullable()`